# self и передача аргументов в функцию python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, функции, классы

Вот есть такой код:

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None

def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    dummy = cur = ListNode(0)
    carry = 0
    while l1 or l2 or carry:
        if l1:
            carry += l1.val
            l1 = l1.next
        if l2:
            carry += l2.val
            l2 = l2.next
        cur.next = ListNode(carry%10)
        cur = cur.next
        carry //=10
    return dummy.next
l1 = [2, 4, 3]
l2 = [5, 6, 4]
addTwoNumbers(l1, l2)
```

Но пишет, что одного аргумента addtwonumbers не хватает. Как я должен передать аргументы в функцию, чтобы она заработала?

Comment: у вас лишний параметр `self` в функции `addTwoNumbers `

Comment: @MaxU в смысле? он же нужен, чтобы использовать класс Listnode. Если я его уберу, все равно будет ошибка.

Comment: если `addTwoNumbers` - это метод класса `ListNode`, то исправьте отступы - `def addTwoNumbers` - должен иметь такой же отступ как `def __init__`

Comment: @MaxU так это не метод класса Listnode, иначе я бы не использовал Listnode в аргументах.

Comment: Вы не используете вроде никакие поля экземпляра класса, поэтому self не нужен.

Comment: Я уже убирал self из аргументов addtwonumbers. Выходит ошибка: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'

Comment: @randomuser228, у вас какая-то путаница. Либо функция `addTwoNumbers ` - это метод класса и тогда у нее должен быть параметр `self`. Если же это независимая от класса функция и определена __вне__ класса, тогда параметр `self` - это просто обязательный параметр с наименованием `self` и он __никакого__ отношения не имеет к каким-либо классам или их атрибутам

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что если addtwonumbers - независимая функция, то self не нужен. Но почему тогда, когда я убираю self, выскакивает ошибка AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'?

Comment: @randomuser228, потому что вы передаете в качестве параметров списки вместо объектов класса `ListNode`. PS а вообще здесь принято задавать вопрос об одной конкретной проблеме и на первый ваш вопрос вы уже получили ответ ;)

Comment: Нет, потому что не заработало)

Answer (score 3):

У вас лишний параметр `self` в функции `addTwoNumbers`.

Но лучше перегрузите оператор `+` для вашего класса:

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None

     def __add__(self, other: ListNode) -> ListNode:
         val = self.val + other.val
         next = ...
         return self.__init__(val, next)
```

после этого можно будет делать так:

```
l1 = ListNode(...)
l2 = ListNode(...)
l3 = l1 + l2
```

Comment: мне хочется попробовать для начала как-то без add, чтобы точно разобраться с self.

Comment: @randomuser228 Почему вы считаеете, что приведённый в ответе пример не поможет вым точно разобраться с self? Сформулируете, пожалуйста, доступно, что остаётся для вас не ясным.  Так как вы ещё не освоили основы основ, то может вы привели для вас очень сложный пример в вопросе?  Если да, попробуйте его упростить и задайте новый вопрос.